# How to install pbrt-v3 on windows10 with Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c++, graphics, cmake, visual-studio-2017, pbrt

I fork the repo and download it, then open it in the Visual Studio 2017 community and did as follows:

```
1:right-click the MakeLists.txt and click the Rebuild All. (x64 Debug)
2:Then, i found the build directory at here:C:\Users\SHIZU-NOTEBOOK\AppData\Local\CMakeBuild\233159a3-9dca-9735-91fc-be7911e3ef6d\build\x64-Debug\Debug
```

I can't find the directory like *\bin, also in cmd "pbrt" dosen't work.

Am I wrong with build?and solution!

Sincerely!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the cmake-gui or cmake command line tool to generate Visual Studio solution file, then build the solution.

If you choose the command line, here are steps:

1. Generate solution files

   ```
   mkdir build && cd build
   cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 15 Win64"
   ```
2. Now,  open `PBRT-V3.sln` with Visual Studio 2017
3. Buile the solution

PS: from the readme in pbrt-v3 project, you need run `git submodule update --init --recursive` to fetch the dependencies.